# Unable to extract video filenames and message_id from a specific Telegram supergroup topic

Tags: python, telethon

I'm trying to list the last 50 uploaded video filenames on a Telegram supergroup topic with the intention of getting both the names of the uploaded files and their message_id at the same time

id of supergroup `-1001867911973`
specific topic inside this supergroup is `https://t.me/lasoffittadownloads/664`

i try to extract information in this way:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types import DocumentAttributeFilename
from datetime import datetime

api_id = 27xxxxxx  # Replace YOUR_API_ID with your api_id from Telegram.
api_hash = 'b5b09783707618xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  # Replace YOUR_API_HASH with your api_hash from Telegram.
phone_number = '+39xxxxxxxxxx'  # Replace with your phone number associated with your Telegram account.

channel_id = '-1001867911973'  # Replace with the correct ID for your channel.

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.connect()

    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        await client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

    try:
        channel_entity = await client.get_entity(int(channel_id))
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Errore: The channel with the ID could not be found '{channel_id}'. Make sure you are using the correct channel ID.")
        return
        
        
    # Link to the specific topic in the channel
    topic_link = "https://t.me/lasoffittadownloads/664"

    print(f"Getting list of latest 50 video files (MP4, MKV) from channel '{channel_entity.title}'...")

    video_files = []
    async for msg in client.iter_messages(channel_entity, limit=50, reverse=True):
        if msg.text and topic_link in msg.text:  # Check if the message contains text and the link to the topic
            if msg.media is not None:
                if hasattr(msg.media, 'document') and msg.media.document.mime_type.startswith('video'):
                    for attr in msg.media.document.attributes:
                        if isinstance(attr, DocumentAttributeFilename):
                            video_files.append(attr.file_name)
                            break

    print("List of video file names:")
    for file_name in video_files:
        print(file_name)

    # Save video filenames in a utf-8 encoded text file
    with open("nomi_file_video.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write("\n".join(video_files))

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I try to get the original filename and its message id but from console I get an empty list, nothing is listed

```
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\script\telebot> python telebot_x.py
Getting the list of latest 50 video files (MP4, MKV) from channel 'La Soffitta [Downloads]'...
Video File Name List:
```

I see that ID of specific topic is this `https://web.telegram.org/a/#-1867911973_664` but if I use `-1867911973_664` or `-1001867911973664` as channel_id i get an error

```
Error: The channel with the ID '#-1867911973_664' could not be found. Make sure you are using the correct channel ID.
```

i looked on https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message but i don't know how to implement the filenames and message_id extraction using `message_thread_id`